# Formula: How to convert 24 hour time format to 12 hour time format

Tags: apex, formula, custom-object, custom-field, datetime

I have a date/time field `Due_Date__c` which I am using as a default value in an email quick action body. The return type of this formula is Text.

Here is the Due_Date__c field output: `2022-03-24 16:00:00Z`

Here is what I have achieved using Apex class:

```
String formatedDate = Due_Date__c.format('yyyy-dd-MM h:mm a');
```

It worked but we want to remove the dependency of Apex class and go with formula field instead.

Is there anyway that I can convert this field into 12 hour format in this way `2022-03-24 4:00 PM` using formula field. Please suggest

Comment: Please [edit] your post to describe what have you tried, include the details of your formula, and describe the specific issue you have encountered.

Comment: @DavidCheng, updated the post with required details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is, but it's going to involve work and has some serious limitations.

#### tl;dr

Anything beyond simple datetime math (adding/subtracting whole days, adding hours/minutes/seconds that fit neatly into the tenths/hundredths/thousandths respectively) is much better left to Apex.

That is something of the form `My_Datetime__c + 7.525`, which would add
7 days,
12 hours (0.5 days),
and 36 minutes (0.025 days)

#### long version

Datetime fields are displayed using formatting based on the user's locale. Deviating from that becomes very tedious, very quickly.

Displaying datetime fields as text (as you're trying to do here) means that you'll be working with the UTC (a.k.a. GMT) value rather than the timezone-adjusted value. You also lose the benefit of Salesforce's handling of Daylight Saving Time/Summer Time. You can probably get the current User's time region indicator (e.g. 'america/chicago') using `$User.TimeZoneSidKey`. You can turn some of those values into timezone offsets, but trying to handle all possible timezone SIDs would put you well beyond the character limit for formulas.

The Date portion is simple, you can just extract it using `DATEVALUE()`.
You can similarly extract the Time portion by using `TIMEVALUE()`.

Since formulas can't have variables (there is [an idea for this](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdeD6UAJ/temporary-variables-in-formulas), but it's been 11 years with no response from the product team), you'd need to use `TIMEVALUE()` 4 times. Once each for the hours, minutes, and seconds; one final time for the AM/PM determination.

The minutes and seconds could be passed through without any additional work.
The AM/PM determination based on a simple check to see if the hour portion is >= 12.

Finally, turning 0-23 (hours) into 1-12 (hours) is the hardest part. The `MOD()` function can easily get us to 0-11 with `MOD(HOURS(TIMEVALUE(Datetime_Field__c)), 12)`. The issue is that we want to map 0 to 12, but leave everything else alone. The most straightforward way to handle that would be to use `CASE()`, e.g.

```
/* This could be shortened by substituting everything after "0, 12," with the same */
/* "myInteger" expression, though at the cost of increasing your compile size */
CASE(myInteger,
    0, 12,
    1, 1, 
    2, 2,
    ...
    10, 10
    11
)
```

+edit:
After looking around a little more, ((x - 1) + k) %k would cause 0 to be mapped to 11, 1 to 0, 2 to 1, etc...
Doing that and adding 1 afterwords achieves what you'd be looking for.

```
MOD(
    (
        MOD(
            HOURS(TIMEVALUE(Datetime_Field__c)), 
            12
        ) 
        + 11
    ),
    12
) 
+ 1
```

-edit

So it is possible if you can ignore the timezone and DST issues, but removing a single line of code from a trigger and replacing it with a complex formula isn't really a trade I would make.
It is possible, but not what I would call a good idea.
You should strongly consider keeping this work in Apex.

Comment: I started writing this up but your's is by far the better one. Great answer!